# translation followed by rotation

Tags: geometry

I am kind of confused about 2D transformations. I read that rotation always has to be done about the origin. But there are questions in which you are supposed to translate first and then rotate. Translation will move the shape away from the origin.

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Any point on the plane can be chosen as the center of rotation,

Comment: The claim of rotation about the origin is just not right. Such rotation is "easy to implement" but not mandatory - it is preferred.

Comment: "rotation always has to be done about the origin": this is plain wrong.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, there are many ways to deal with rotations and translations. If we just consider isometries in a flat plane, all these ways mostly come down to the same thing but the way the ideas are organized and expressed can be different. If you ever get back to this question and want a better answer, you might try editing the question to show an actual example of a rotation the way it was defined to you. Then someone might be able to explain things in terms that relate to what you already know.

Answer (score 4):

*If* you describe a rotation by a [matrix times vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) in the simple sense, *then* that rotation is a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), as such preserves the origin, and therefore must have the origin as its center.

If you want to describe a different kind of rotation, you need a formalism which isn't restricted to linear transformations. Often one uses [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), which can be [described by a matrix multiplication followed by a vector addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation). Or you can describe your points using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), and again [use matrices to describe the transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix), albeit larger ones. A general “matrix times homogeneous coordinate vector” transformation would be a [projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation), which can model any transformation of the (real) plane as long as it preserves lines as lines.

When rotating around an arbitrary point in the plane, it is often convenient to think of this as a sequence of three transformations: translate that point to the origin, then rotate about the origin, then translate back. Such a sequence can be combined to a single transformation e.g. by multiplying the corresponding transformation matrices. In a multiply-then-add formalism, combining transformations is harder to understand, so I really suggest using [augmented matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation around the origin is obtained by

$$R\,p.$$

Rotation around an arbitrary center is obtained by

$$R\,(p-c)+c.$$

---

You can rotate around the origin, then translate

$$R\,p+t$$

or translate, then rotate around the origin,

$$R\,(p+t).$$

Notice that

$$R\,(p+t)=R\,p+R\,t$$

so that these transformations are equivalent with

$$t\leftrightarrow R\,t.$$

---

Now for the strong, rotation around the center $c$, followed by a translation,

$$R\,(p-c)+c+t=R\,p+(-R\,c+c+t)=R\,(p+(-c+R^{-1}c+R^{-1}t)),$$

and translation followed by rotation around $c$,

$$R\,(p+t-c)+c=R\,p+(R\,t-R\,c+c)=R\,(p+(t-c+R^{-1}c)).$$

This shows that any combined transformation can be expressed as a rotation around the origin followed by a translation, or conversely. This remains true if you compose several rotations and/or translations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that OP's confusing is: why there is a different effect between `translation followed by rotation` and `rotation followed by translation`. If so, I give here simple explanation, both for rotation (around the origin) and rotation around some point.

1. **Mathematical Explanation** Translation and rotation are transformations, say $T(x)=x+b$ and $R(x)=Ax$ with $A$ is $2\times 2$ matrix; and in generally, their product
   $$T(R(x))=T(Ax)=Ax+b,$$
   $$R(Tx)=R(x+b)=A(x+b)=Ax+Ab$$
   is NOT commutative, that is $T R\not= R T$.
2. **Graphical Explanation** For the simplest case, given a point $A$. When rotating it with angle `ROT` and then shifting to `SHI`, we get the red curve. Similarly, when shifting it to `SHI` and then rotating it with angle `ROT`, we get the blue curve. As you see, they are much different.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
import math;
import graph;
add(grid(5,5,gray));
axes("$x$","$y$",gray);
pair A=(2.5,1), O=(0,0);
real ROT=35;
pair SHI=(2,1);
pair M=shift(SHI)*rotate(ROT)*A;
pair N=rotate(ROT)*shift(SHI)*A;

path A1=arc(O,abs(A),degrees(A),degrees(A)+ROT);
path  A1r=relpoint(A1,1)--relpoint(A1,1)+SHI;
path AtoM=A1&A1r;
draw(AtoM,red);

pair A2=A+SHI;
path AtoN=A--A2&arc(O,abs(A2),degrees(A2),degrees(A2)+ROT);
draw(AtoN,blue);

dot("$O$",O,SW);
dot("$A$",A,S);
dot(Label("$M$",Fill(white)),M,1.5S,red);
dot("$N$",N,plain.N,blue);
```